# convert sql query to php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been trying to get sum from my table. However i seem to get results with sql but not with CodeIgniter although i make sure the query is similar. 
i get no results and i don't know what exactly i'm doing wrong.

**MySql query**

```
SELECT SUM( amount_paid ) AS theSum
FROM invoice
WHERE MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =10
AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =2015
```

**My CodeIgniter query**

```
<?php 
  echo $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM invoice WHERE MONTH (creation_timestamp` ) = 10) AS invoice');

  $query = $this->db->get('invoice'); 
?>
```

**and I also tried**

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="
 <?php 
  $this->db->select('SUM(amount_paid) as total');
  $this->db->where('creation_timestamp', 10);
  $q=$this->db->get('invoice');
  $row=$q->row();
  $total=$row->total;
 ?>"

  data-postfix="" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">0</div>

  <h3><?php echo $total ;?></h3>
  <p>Total Payments</p>
</div>
```

**MY schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice`(
 `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `amount_paid` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `due` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `creation_timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_timestamp` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `payment_method` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `payment_details` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'paid or unpaid',
 PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34244773/ where I gave you a link to check for errors. Plus, why the mysql and sql-server tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244773/sum-of-column-by-timestamp-month

Comment: this one is mainly about converting mysql query i just posted the rest to help out

Comment: and btw your comment is a duplicate!

Comment: Would you add 2 or 3 row records in order to run and write query best on your records?

Comment: You don't use the same queries. Missing `FROM_UNIXTIME` in CI query.

Answer (score 1):

According to your MySQL query,codeIgniter active record will work,

```
$this->db->select("SUM( amount_paid ) AS theSum");
$this->db->from("invoice");
$this->db->where("MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =10",null, true);
$this->db->where("YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =2015",null,true);
$rec = $this->db->get();
```

MySQL output will be :

```
SELECT SUM( amount_paid ) AS theSum 
FROM `invoice` 
WHERE MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) = 10 
AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) = 2015
```

Or, you can directy put your query inside active records like:

```
$rec = "SELECT SUM( amount_paid ) AS theSum
FROM invoice
WHERE MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =10
AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =2015";

$this->db->query($rec);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select_sum("amount_paid", "theSum")
  ->from("invoice")
  ->where("MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) )", 10)
  ->where("YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) )", 2015);

$rec = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank you bilal for your Response. I have tried both yours and nimatullah's example. but they don't seem to work. Is it possible to be a controllers issue ? i mean it should work. but it doesn't show the result at all

Comment: you can `echo $rec` to see what query is being built.

Comment: how i get $rec output in model?